# JsonTextReader gets mixed up after networking error

Tags: c#, json, .net, sockets

I am trying to make a program that uses data to find solutions to large 3D mathematical nets. In JSON format, there is an array of nodes and information about their position in 3D space and what properties do they have etc. using line delimited format:

```
{"ID": 1, "Type": "Node", "OtherInfo":["info1", "info2"], "x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0}
{"ID": 2, "Type": "OtherNode", "OtherInfo":["otherinfo1", "otherinfo2"], "x": 1, "y": 0, "z": 0}
...
```

My class:

```
class Node
{
    ulong ID { get; set; }
    nodeType Type { get; set; }
    string[] otherInfo { get; set; }
    decimal X { get; set; }
    decimal Y { get; set; }
    decimal Z { get; set; }
}
```

My methind of getting things:

```
public static IEnumerable<Node> ReadStream(Stream stream)
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    using var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader) { SupportMultipleContent = true };

    Stopwatch foo = new Stopwatch();

    bool ll = jsonReader.Read();
    while (ll)
    {
        Node node = null;
        try
        {
            node = serializer.Deserialize<Node>(jsonReader);
            ll = jsonReader.Read();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception {e}");
            continue;
        }
        yield return node;
    }
}
```

I am passing the varible `var stream = await HttpClient.GetStreamAsync("https://example.com/nodes.jsonl");` into the function and it works well *most* of the time, it fails once every 1/50000 nodes. The problem is once it fails, in the 65,000 nodes it starts reading the `"info1"`'s and `"otherinfo1"`'s as nodes needing to be desierlized on the object that failed to deserilize.

```
Exception Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "info1" to type 'Starbreaker.Node'. Path 'type', line 61876, position 295. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to Starbreaker.Node.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable(Object value, Type initialType, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast(Object initialValue, CultureInfo culture, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
   at Starbreaker.settings.<ReadStream>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\repos\Starbreaker\Starbreaker\Form1.cs:line 361
```

Here is one of the networking errors I get:

```
Exception System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Http.DelegatingStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer(Char[] userBuffer, Int32 userOffset, Int32 desiredChars, Boolean& readToUserBuffer)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.Read(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadData(Boolean append, Int32 charsRequired)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringIntoBuffer(Char quote)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseProperty()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseObject()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
   at Starbreaker.settings.<ReadStream>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\repos\Starbreaker\Starbreaker\Form1.cs:line 361
```

It seems that the read function sill moves the posistion on regardless if there is an error or not. Is there a way to move it back to the beginning of the line when a networking error happens or is there another way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what's going on with the server, but I am going to concentrate on how you can recover from parsing a stream of independent JSON blocks. The issue is you are probably getting malformed data which `Newtonsoft.Json` can not recover from. Once that happens, you are out of luck. Not even [adding error handling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm) to your routine will work in this case. So, what you should consider is something like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<Node> ReadStream(Stream stream)
{
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        Node node;
        try
        {
            node = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Node>(line);
        }
        catch (JsonReaderException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to parse line: {line}\nException: {ex}");
            continue;
        }
        yield return node;
    }
}
```

If there is malformed data, it won't matter. You are delegating the responsibility of reading lines to something that's really good at it and will never error under normal circumstances (normal circumstances is a *good stream* with well-formed or malformed data)

I tried it with your data and intentionally threw in bad data. This method just skipped right over the bad data and continued on to the next line.